# How do I display time column as hh:mm tt in datagridview which is retrieved from MYSQL time field?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am having a column LOGINTIME as TIME datatype in MYSQL.

This column has more values such as

```
11:59:00

11:45:34

14:22:22
```

I want to display this column in datagridview as 'hh:mm tt'
I mean,

```
11:59 AM

11:45 AM

02:22 PM
```

Code:

```
dataGridView1.Columns["LOGINTIME"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "hh:mm tt";
```

This is the code I used, it displays me an error.

http://postimg.org/image/fm01hhyzp/

```
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Columns["LOGINTIME"].ValueType.ToString());
```

It displays "System.TimeSpan". So how to format a TimeSpan column in datagridview as "hh:mm tt"

Comment: What error is it showing ?

Comment: Without your error message, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Please post the error *and* the code. .NET has no problem reading data as date and time, nor does DataGridView have any problems displaying DateTime and TimeSpan values. How do you read the data and how do you bind the grid to the data?

Comment: It's impossible to help without the error and the code. BTW, ADO.NET will return date types as DateTime and TIME as TimeSpan if you don't force any string conversions. A DataGridViewTextBox column has no problems binding to and formatting such properties.

Comment: I have included the image link of error screenshot

Comment: @HarveySpecter I have included the screenshot. Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET accepts the TIME datatype of MYSQL as System.TimeSpan not System.DateTime.

Here you are trying to assign custom DateTime format, that why you get error as "Input string was not in a correct format".

You need to assign custom TimeSpan format, like

```
dataGridView1.Columns["LOGINTIME"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"hh\:mm";
```

Check this link to know more about custom TimeSpan format

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

By default, TimeSpan doesn't support 12hr time format.

You need to convert TimeSpan to DateTime object and specify any custom DateTime format as you want.

Answer (score -1):

Check my edited answer...

```
   dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Cells["LOGINTIME"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.Rows[Index].Cells["LOGINTIME"].Value).ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: I get the following error Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn'

Comment: This code tries to modify the DataColumn object itself, not the cell value

Comment: You can't get a *row's* value by calling `.Value` on a column. There is no such property

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos your concerns were right . actually it was just an idea how you can do this. anyways here is my proper answer.